# Keep file download list of each authenticated users

Tags: users, files

I have a content type "Application" and each "Application" content has a downloadable file.

I'd like to keep the downloaded file list, actually node list, & count for each authenticated users.

Is there any ready-made module provided for this feature ?
Or
How can I achieve it by programming ?

Comment: Look into the [hook_file_download](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21File%21file.api.php/function/hook_file_download/8.2.x), add your logic there.

Answer (score 0):

The [Download Count](http://drupal.org/project/download_count) module may be useful. The module page says

> The download_count module tracks downloads of private files attached
>   to nodes via the core upload or contributed filefield modules for d6
>   and private core file fields for d7.

But it has only development version for D7.